# Conflict in applying rules during Reading ICD text file

Tags: java, text

**LINE READING RULES:**

1. no indent/dash == **major disease**
2. one indent/dash(-) == **subIndent1**
3. two indent/dash(--)== **subIndent2**
4. three indent/dash(---)== **subIndent3**
5. four indent/dash(----)== **subIndent4**
6. five indent/dash(-----)== **subIndent5**
7. six indent/dash(-----)== **subIndent6**

**Disease.txt**(original short sample)

 http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/dvs/2e_volume3_2014.pdf (full Disease ICD file sample)

```
Aars Q87.1
Abdomen, abdominal — see also condition
- acute R10.0
-- convulsive 
equivalent G40.8
Abdominalgia R10.4
Abduction contracture, hip or other joint —see Contraction, joint
Aberrant (congenital) — see also Malposition, congenital
- adrenal gland Q89.1
- artery (peripheral) NEC Q27.8
- breast Q83.8
Aberration, mental F99.0
- endocrine gland NEC Q89.2
- hepatic duct Q44.5
- pancreas Q45.3
-- vein (peripheral) 
pender NEC Q27.8
```

I have tried following code. All Above rules are working fine on reading line by line **Disease** text file.

**Bean for major disease: DiseaseCategory.java**

```
public class DiseaseCategory {
        private int mdId;
        private String mdName;
        private String mdCode;

        DiseaseCategory(int mdId, String mdName, String mdCode){
            this.mdId=mdId;
            this.mdName=mdName;
            this.mdCode=mdCode;
//setter and getters below
        }
```

**Bean for sub indent disease: SubDiseaseCategory .java**

```
public class SubDiseaseCategory {
SubDiseaseCategory(int sdId,    int mdId,   String sdIndent1,String sdCode1,
    String sdIndent2, String sdCode2, String sdIndent3,String sdCode3,String sdIndent4,String sdCode4,
    String sdIndent5,String sdCode5,String sdIndent6, String sdCode6)
{
        this.sdId=sdId;
        this.mdId=mdId;
        this.sdIndent1=sdIndent1;
        this.sdCode1=sdCode1;
        this.sdIndent2=sdIndent2;
        this.sdCode2=sdCode2;
        this.sdIndent3=sdIndent3;
        this.sdCode3=sdCode3;
        this.sdIndent4=sdIndent4;
        this.sdCode4=sdCode4;
        this.sdIndent5=sdIndent5;
        this.sdCode5=sdCode5;
        this.sdIndent6=sdIndent6;
        this.sdCode6=sdCode6;
    }

    private int sdId;   
    private int mdId;   
    private String sdIndent1;   
    private String sdCode1  ;
    private String sdIndent2;   
    private String sdCode2  ;   
    private String sdIndent3;   
    private String sdCode3  ;
    private String sdIndent4;   
    private String sdCode4  ;
    private String sdIndent5;   
    private String sdCode5  ;   
    private String sdIndent6;   
    private String sdCode6  ;
//all setters and getters
}
```

**Main function performing in DataMigeration.java**

```
public class DataMigeration
{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{   
        String FILE_NAME="c://com/best/uibeans/diseases.txt";
        File file=new File(FILE_NAME);

        DataMigeration ob=new DataMigeration();
        //ob.connection();
        ob.readAndSaveFile(file);
}
private Connection conn=null;
private Statement stmt=null;

public void connection() {
    String userName = "guest";
    String password = "";
    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://JAVASERVER2\\MTS;databaseName=ICD";
    try {   
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded.........");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver not Loaded..........");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);    
 System.out.println("Connection  Established..........");
    stmt=conn.createStatement();    
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
System.out.println("Connection not Established..........");
}   
}
public void SaveMajorDisease(int mdId, String mdName, String mdCode){
    try {
        String query="";
        mdName= mdName.replace("'", "");
        mdName=mdName.trim();

        query="insert into MAJOR_DISEASE(md_id, md_name, md_code) " +
                "values ("+mdId+",'"+mdName+"','"+mdCode+"')";
        c(query);       
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Data Inserted Succesfully....");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Data Not Inserted Succesfully....");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void SaveSubDisease(
        int sdId,           int mdId,
        String sdIndent1,   String sdCode1,
        String sdIndent2,   String sdCode2,
        String sdIndent3,   String sdCode3,
        String sdIndent4,   String sdCode4,
        String sdIndent5,   String sdCode5,
        String sdIndent6,   String sdCode6  
        ){
    try {
        String query="";
        sdIndent1= sdIndent1.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent1=sdIndent1.trim();

        sdIndent2= sdIndent2.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent2=sdIndent2.trim();

        sdIndent3= sdIndent3.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent3=sdIndent3.trim();

        sdIndent4= sdIndent4.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent4=sdIndent4.trim();

        sdIndent5= sdIndent5.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent5=sdIndent5.trim();

        sdIndent6= sdIndent6.replace("'", "");
        sdIndent6=sdIndent6.trim();


         query="insert into SUB_DISEASE(sd_id, md_id, " +
                " sd_indent1, sd_code1 , " +
                " sd_indent2, sd_code2 , " +
                " sd_indent3, sd_code3 , " +
                " sd_indent4, sd_code4 , " +
                " sd_indent5, sd_code5 , " +
                " sd_indent6, sd_code6  " +
                " ) " +
                "values ("+sdId+","+mdId+", " +
                " '"+sdIndent1+"' , '"+sdCode1+"' , " +
                "'"+sdIndent2+"' , '"+sdCode2+"' ," +
                "'"+sdIndent3+"' , '"+sdCode3+"' ," +
                "'"+sdIndent4+"' , '"+sdCode4+"' ," +
                "'"+sdIndent5+"' , '"+sdCode5+"' ," +
                "'"+sdIndent6+"' , '"+sdCode6+"' " +
                " ) ";
        c(query);
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Data Inserted Succesfully....");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Data Not Inserted Succesfully....");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readAndSaveFile(File file)
{
    List<DiseaseCategory> majorDiseaseList=new ArrayList<DiseaseCategory>();
    List<SubDiseaseCategory> subDiseaseList=new ArrayList<SubDiseaseCategory>();
    try
     {
         String data="";
         String line;
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String majorDiseaseCode="";
        String majorDisease="";

         String sdIndent1="";   
         String sdCode1=""  ;

         String sdIndent2="";   
         String sdCode2=""  ;

         String sdIndent3="";   
         String sdCode3=""  ;

         String sdIndent4="";   
         String sdCode4=""  ;

         String sdIndent5="";   
         String sdCode5=""  ;

         String sdIndent6="";   
         String sdCode6=""  ;
// _________________________________________________________//
/* major disease record:    majorDiseaseList                */      
int mdId=0;
int sdId=0;                 

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
         {

            majorDisease="";
            majorDiseaseCode="";
   if(!line.equals("")){
            if(lineContainsNoIndentAtFirst(line)==0)
                {   
                    String tokens[]=line.split(" ");    
                for(int i=0;i<tokens.length;i++)
                {
                    if(tokens[i].contains("."))     if(tokens[i]!="0")  majorDiseaseCode=tokens[i];
                    if(!tokens[i].contains("."))        if(tokens[i]!="0")  majorDisease+=" "+tokens[i];                    

                }   
                if(!majorDisease.equals(null) && !majorDisease.equals("") && majorDisease!="" && majorDisease!=null){

                        mdId++;                                             
                        majorDiseaseList.add(new DiseaseCategory(mdId, majorDisease, majorDiseaseCode));
                }                           
            }//end if
            else if(lineContainsNoIndentAtFirst(line)!=0)// for no dash or no any suffix at beginning
            {        
                sdId++;             
                if(lineContainsOneIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for one '-' only
                {
                    String tokens1[]=line.split(" ");
                    sdIndent1="";
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens1.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens1[i].contains("."))        if(tokens1[i]!="0") sdCode1=tokens1[i];
                            if(!tokens1[i].contains("."))       if(tokens1[i]!="0") sdIndent1+=" "+tokens1[i];
                            sdIndent1= sdIndent1.replace("-", "");
                        }
                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,
                                                                        sdIndent1,
                                                                        sdCode1,"","","","","","","","","",""
                                                                    ));
                }//end if: lineContainsOneIndentAtFirst()
                else if(lineContainsTwoIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for two '--' only
                {
                    String tokens2[]=line.split(" ");
                    sdIndent2="";
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens2.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens2[i].contains("."))        if(tokens2[i]!="0") sdCode2=tokens2[i];
                            if(!tokens2[i].contains("."))       if(tokens2[i]!="0") sdIndent2+=" "+tokens2[i];
                            sdIndent2= sdIndent2.replace("-", "");
                        }
                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,"","",
                                                                        sdIndent2,
                                                                        sdCode2,"","","","","", "", "", ""                              
                                                                    ));                                                         
                }//end if: lineContainsTwoIndentAtFirst()           
                else if(lineContainsThreeIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for three '---' only
                {
                    String tokens3[]=line.split(" ");
                    sdIndent3="";
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens3.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens3[i].contains("."))        if(tokens3[i]!="0") sdCode3=tokens3[i];
                            if(!tokens3[i].contains("."))       if(tokens3[i]!="0") sdIndent3+=" "+tokens3[i];
                            sdIndent3= sdIndent3.replace("-", "");
                        }
                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,"","","","",
                                                                        sdIndent3,
                                                                        sdCode3,"","","",   "", "", ""                              
                                                                    ));                                                         
                }//end if: lineContainsThreeIndentAtFirst()         
                else if(lineContainsFourIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for Four '----' only
                {
                    String tokens4[]=line.split(" ");
                    sdIndent4="";
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens4.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens4[i].contains("."))        if(tokens4[i]!="0") sdCode4=tokens4[i];
                            if(!tokens4[i].contains("."))       if(tokens4[i]!="0") sdIndent4+=" "+tokens4[i];
                            sdIndent4= sdIndent4.replace("-", "");
                        }
                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,"","","","","","",
                                                                        sdIndent4,
                                                                        sdCode4,"", "", "", ""                              
                                                                    ));                                                         
                }//end if: lineContainsFourIndentAtFirst()          
                else if(lineContainsFiveIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for Four '----' only
                {
                    String tokens5[]=line.split(" ");
                    sdIndent5="";
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens5.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens5[i].contains("."))        if(tokens5[i]!="0") sdCode5=tokens5[i];
                            if(!tokens5[i].contains("."))       if(tokens5[i]!="0") sdIndent5+=" "+tokens5[i];
                            sdIndent5= sdIndent5.replace("-", "");
                        }

                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,"","","","","","","","",
                                                                        sdIndent5,
                                                                        sdCode5,    "", ""                              
                                                                    ));                                                         
                }//end if: lineContainsFiveIndentAtFirst()          
                else if(lineContainsSixIndentAtFirst(line)==0) // for Four '----' only
                {
                    String tokens6[]=line.split(" ");
                        for(int i=0;i<tokens6.length;i++)
                        {
                            if(tokens6[i].contains("."))        if(tokens6[i]!="0") sdCode6=tokens6[i];
                            if(!tokens6[i].contains("."))       if(tokens6[i]!="0") sdIndent6+=" "+tokens6[i];
                            sdIndent6= sdIndent6.replace("-", "");
                        }                       
                            subDiseaseList.add(new SubDiseaseCategory(
                                                                        sdId,
                                                                        mdId,"","","","","","","","","","",
                                                                        sdIndent6,
                                                                        sdCode6                             
                                                                    ));                         
                }//end if: 5indent          
         }//end if: suffix: '-'
        }//if for not null index
      }// end while loop for line by line reading from text
//Retrieving.....
int maxRecords=1;         
int masterMax=1;
      for(DiseaseCategory obj: majorDiseaseList){
              masterMax++;                
//            System.out.print("\n"+obj.getMdId()+" : "+obj.getMdName()+" : "+obj.getMdCode());
              //saving Major disease
              String mdName=obj.getMdName();
//              String tokensEscape[]=mdName.split("\'");
//                  for(int i=0;i<tokensEscape.length;i++)  mdName+="\'"+tokensEscape[i];
//                  
//                    System.out.print("\n"+obj.getMdId()+" : "+mdName+" : "+obj.getMdCode());
//                  
              SaveMajorDisease(obj.getMdId(),mdName,obj.getMdCode());             
      }


      System.out.println("\n____size:"+subDiseaseList.size()+"_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n");

      for(SubDiseaseCategory obj: subDiseaseList){
              maxRecords++;       
              String msg="";
              msg+= obj.getSdId()+"     : "+obj.getMdId();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent1().equals(""))    msg+= ":    i:      "+obj.getSdIndent1()+" :             \t\t\tcode1:   "+obj.getSdCode1();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent2().equals(""))    msg+= ":    ii:     "+obj.getSdIndent2()+" :             \t\t\tcode2:   "+obj.getSdCode2();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent3().equals(""))    msg+= ":    iii:    "+obj.getSdIndent3()+" :             \t\t\tcode3:   "+obj.getSdCode3();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent4().equals(""))    msg+= ":    iv:     "+obj.getSdIndent4()+" :             \t\t\tcode4:   "+obj.getSdCode4();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent5().equals(""))    msg+= ":    v:  "+obj.getSdIndent5()+" :                 \t\t\tcode5:   "+obj.getSdCode5();
              if(!obj.getSdIndent6().equals(""))    msg+= ":    vi:     "+obj.getSdIndent6()+" :             \t\t\tcode6:   "+obj.getSdCode6();
        //    System.out.println(msg);  


//saving sub_disease              
              SaveSubDisease(
                                obj.getSdId(),          obj.getMdId(),
                                obj.getSdIndent1(),     obj.getSdCode1(),
                                obj.getSdIndent2(),     obj.getSdCode2(),
                                obj.getSdIndent3(),     obj.getSdCode3(),
                                obj.getSdIndent4(),     obj.getSdCode4(),
                                obj.getSdIndent5(),     obj.getSdCode5(),
                                obj.getSdIndent6(),     obj.getSdCode6()
                            );
      }

      br.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe){}
}

public  int lineContainsNoIndentAtFirst(String str)
{       
      int contains=0;         

//  if(!str.startsWith("-"))
//  {
          String dashCheck = str.substring(0,1)+""; 
          if( dashCheck.contains("-"))   contains++;
          if(!dashCheck.contains("-"))   contains=0;

//          String tokensDotCheck[]=str.split(" ");
//              for(int i=0;i<tokensDotCheck.length;i++)
//              {
//                  if(i==0){                       
//                      if(tokensDotCheck[i].contains(".")){
//                          contains++;
//                      }                       
//                  }
//              }
//        
//  }else{
//      contains++;
//  }

          return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsOneIndentAtFirst(String str)
{
          String dashCheck = str.substring(0,3)+""; 
          int contains=0;         
          if(dashCheck.contains("- -"))  contains++;                  
          return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsTwoIndentAtFirst(String str){       
          String dashCheck = str.substring(0,6)+""; 
          int contains=0;
          if(dashCheck.contains("- - - ")) contains++;
          return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsThreeIndentAtFirst(String str){     
        String dashCheck = str.substring(0,8)+"";   
        int contains=0;
        if(dashCheck.contains("- - - - ")) contains++;    
      return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsFourIndentAtFirst(String str){      
      String dashCheck = str.substring(0,10)+"";    
      int contains=0;
     if(dashCheck.contains("- - - - - "))   contains++;
      return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsFiveIndentAtFirst(String str){      
      String dashCheck = str.substring(0,12)+"";    
      int contains=0;
     if(dashCheck.contains("- - - - - - "))  contains++;
      return contains;      
}
public  int lineContainsSixIndentAtFirst(String str){       
      String dashCheck = str.substring(0,14)+"";    
      int contains=0;
     if(dashCheck.contains("- - - - - - "))  contains++;
      return contains;      
}
public void c(String msg){  System.out.print("\n|   "+msg);}

}
```

above code is working fine on rules but problem is below,
**Problem:**

```
Abdomen, abdominal — see also condition
- acute R10.0
-- convulsive 
equivalent G40.8
```

wrapped sub disease indent is counting on Rule 1 that no indent/dash is equals to **major disease** but it that is wrapped text of above line.it should not be counted in major disease but it should be counted in previous sub disease indent line.
how to solve this conflict? 
possibly i have shared all things if any one have any difficulty in giving answer you can ask through comment.I will tell you.

Comment: What are you struggling with exactly ? What is working and what not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not sure you asked a question anywhere in there...

Comment: i have asked in title of question and as well as first line of my question guiding for it.

Comment: @islamuddin Nobody is trying to be difficult, but you have to tell is _where_ you're having trouble.  Are you getting an error?  Are you having difficulty with the flow you are trying to implement?  Help us narrow in on _what exactly_ you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Yes. You didn't ask a question or describe a problem, you just posted your assignment for us.

Comment: @GamerJosh i possibly make question easy now

Comment: @Takendarkk i have described my problem now

Comment: @jeroen_de_schutter i have mentioned the problem now